# I'm stuck at low resolution nvidia driver not working

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution

I've upgraded to the new distro and I can not get the old resolution. I've tried everything so I'm trying this option asking here.
What I've got till now is:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* -y
```

and I get:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-48-generic : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (<= 515.65.01-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (>= 515.65.01) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (<= 515.65.01-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (>= 515.65.01) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

xradr give me this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       0.00* 
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

this lspci | grep VGA ghive me this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
```

I've tried a lot of things but none worked, I would like to solve without formatting everything.

typing `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

i get:

```
   this: `(Reading database ... 298222 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ..
.
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-510
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/l
ibGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-
gl-515'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-li
nux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.0
1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`
```

going further
if i use `apt --fix-broken install`

```
i get:`The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-515
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-515
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/189 MB of archives.
After this operation, 383 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 298222 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ..
.
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-510
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/l
ibGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-
gl-515'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-li
nux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.0
1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

I partially solved for the moment in this way:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-515
dpkg -l |grep nvidia
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo lshw -c video
```

resolution is back but the system say some plugin are missing, if i try to load a video says totem could not start up some plugin are missing.

Comment: What kernel have you upgraded to? If I read this correctly you removed the nvidia driver so as expected the errors include missing nvidia driver. I do not see a version of Ubuntu in your question. Please EDIT the question and add the info.

Comment: 5.15.0-48-generic, sorry the update was of the distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I removed the driver because i was unable to make it work correcly

Comment: And the effect of `sudo apt --fix-broken install` - as suggested - not included above? Try it from the recovery mode; i.e. do fsck, network, then drop to root prompt.

Comment: thank you, in answer i've edited what i get

Answer (score -1):

I solved by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver-515
dpkg -l |grep nvidia
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo lshw -c video
```